# Export a GDB feature class to a GPKG with OGR

Tags: gdal, ogr2ogr, geopackage, feature-class

Suppose I have a feature class in a GDB here: C:\MyDir\MyGDB.gdb\my_dataset\my_feature. I want to export this feature class to a geopackage here: C:\MyDir\MyGPKP.gpkg using the gdal vector tool ogr2ogr. Since I am working outside of an ESRI environment and only need to read from my GDB, I assume I can use the format -f OpenFileGDB. My confusion is how to set up the command line syntax to achieve this. Assuming I am working in my ...\OSGEO4W\bin directory, this is what I have tried:

```
ogr2ogr -f "GPKG" "C:\MyDir\MyGPKP.gpkg\new_feature" "C:\MyDir\MyGDB.gdb" -lco FEATURE_DATASET=my_dataset my_feature
```

I am getting errors about the `Failure to open datasource with the following driver:` I think I do not understand how to properly format my command and cannot seem to find an example of how to do this in the gdal documentation. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`-lco` is a layer *creation* option. Just pass the featureclass name and ignore the feature dataset:

```
ogr2ogr -f GPKG "C:\MyDir\MyGPKP.gpkg" "C:\MyDir\MyGDB.gdb" my_feature
```

And if you want to rename the new gpkg layer, use the `-nln` argument:

```
ogr2ogr -f GPKG "C:\MyDir\MyGPKP.gpkg" -nln newlayername "C:\MyDir\MyGDB.gdb" my_feature
```

Comment: I believe this is the right solution, but....apparently I have some null values that are causing a `failed to execute insert: NOT NULL constraint failed`. I need those nulls. I know there is a tag to either force or remove the default null constraint (-forceNullable & -unsetDefault). Where would I add them to ogr2ogr -f "GPKG" "C:\MyDir\MyGPKP.gpkg" "C:\MyDir\MyGDB.gdb" "my_feature" ?

Comment: I think that needs to be a separate question https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/ask

Comment: Will do. Thanks for the assist.