Converting geodatabase into GeoPackage using ArcGIS Pro
I am using ArcGIS Pro 3.1.2.
Is there a tool that can convert a geodatabase containing multiple vector layers into a GeoPackage?

You can convert your vector feature classes in a gdb into a geopackage, but you may need to do it one layer at a time.
Move your data into the GeoPackage like this:

Create a GeoPackage with the Create SQLite Workspace tool (using the GeoPackage spatial type)
Use the Copy tool (Data Management, General toolset) to add vector data
Use the Add Raster to GeoPackage tool (Conversion, To GeoPackage toolset) to add raster mosaics

From: https://www.esri.com/arcgis-blog/products/product/data-management/how-to-use-ogc-geopackages-in-arcgis-pro/

Or possibly this command line version?: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/443373/export-a-gdb-feature-class-to-a-gpkg-with-ogr
